# BitArray to integer issue

Tags: c#, bitarray

```
public static int getIntegerFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{
  var result = new int[1];
  bitArray.CopyTo(result, 0);
  return result[0];
}

// Input  A) 01110
// Output A) 14
// Input  B) 0011
// Output B) 12 <=== ????? WHY!!! :)
```

Can some one please explain me why my second return value is 12 instead of 3?? Please ... Thank you.

Comment: Please show us how did you use this method, how was Input A & b built.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically it's considering the bits in the opposite order to the way you were expecting - you haven't shown how you're mapping your input binary to a `BitArray`, but the result is treating it as 1100 rather than 0011.

The documentation isn't clear, admittedly, but it does work the way *I'd* expect it to: `bitArray[0]` represents the *least* significant value, just as it usually is when discussing binary (so bit 0 is 0/1, bit 1 is 0/2, bit 2 is 0/4, bit 3 is 0/8 etc). For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(8);
        bits[0] = false;
        bits[1] = true;

        int[] array = new int[1];
        bits.CopyTo(array, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(array[0]); // Prints 2
    }
}
```

Comment: The first input(`01110`) is symmetric, so he didn't not notice... **+1**

Comment: The order actually makes perfect sense once you try to implement a function like CopyTo.

Answer (score 1):

You need rotate bit's to right direction to get right results. 1100 is 12

Comment: No, rotation isn't what's required here - it's reflection. For example, if the OP's input were 1101, the result would be 11 (8 + 2 + 1), and you can't get that by rotating a bit pattern of 1101...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean rotate by 180 ;). Reflection is most appropriate here. if 1101 rotate by 180 we get 1011. 11 ^10 = 1011 ^2

Comment: It's not clear whether you're being flippant or not, but just in *case* you're not, "rotate by 180" would normally mean "rotate through 180 bits" - I would *never* use the term "rotate" for "reflect".

Comment: Reflection is most appropriate here.